# Unity 5 Chartboost Black screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I have implemented Chartboost to my game.
The advert is showing up, If I close it, there is no problem.
If I press the back button also no problem.
If I press on the advert and I press the back button, or just go back to the app the screen goes to black. I can hear the background music going, also I can still play the game but the display is completely black.

I use: Unity 5.0.2f1 (64-bit) with CBUnityPlugin_5_5_3

I'm testing it on Android 5.0.2 phone and 4.4.4 tablet
the result is the same.

```
bool shouldDisplayInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{
    return true;
}
void didDisplayInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{}
void didCacheInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{}
void didFailToLoadInterstitial(CBLocation location, CBImpressionError error)
{}
void didDismissInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{}
void didCloseInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{}
void didClickInterstitial(CBLocation location)
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Main_Menu");
}

void OnDisable() 
{
    Chartboost.didFailToLoadInterstitial -= didFailToLoadInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didDismissInterstitial -= didDismissInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didCloseInterstitial -= didCloseInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didClickInterstitial -= didClickInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didCacheInterstitial -= didCacheInterstitial;
    Chartboost.shouldDisplayInterstitial -= shouldDisplayInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didDisplayInterstitial -= didDisplayInterstitial;
}
void OnEnable() 
{
    Chartboost.didFailToLoadInterstitial += didFailToLoadInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didDismissInterstitial += didDismissInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didCloseInterstitial += didCloseInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didClickInterstitial += didClickInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didCacheInterstitial += didCacheInterstitial;
    Chartboost.shouldDisplayInterstitial += shouldDisplayInterstitial;
    Chartboost.didDisplayInterstitial += didDisplayInterstitial;
}
```

and in my update loop

```
if (adcall)
        {
            variable.dieInc();
            if (variable.getDie() == 3)
            {
                if (Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.Default)) 
                {
                    Chartboost.showInterstitial (CBLocation.Default);
                }
            variable.resetDie();
            }
            adcall = false;
        }
```

Is anyone else have the same effect?

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. Having almost the same issue, but instead of a black screen, the UI does not respond to touches, but unity activity does respond to android back button which shows the quit popup

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by commenthing the **OnGui()** function in **Chartboost.cs** script.

I Hope is not too late!